# Use DidSelectRowAtIndexPath to change a NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I thought I figured out myself how to do this question, but it won't work. The code I used:

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
     //timedText = a NSString

    [timed replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:timedText];
    [SpelerTable reloadData];
}
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? Also, I'd like to not use "replaceObjectAtIndex:1" but use the selected cell.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why index `1` and not `indexPath.row`?  Plus you don't need to reload the whole table; just the row that changed:

```
[timed replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:timedText];
[spelerTable reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                   withRowAnimation:UITableViewAnimationAutomatic];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    [timed replaceObjectAtIndex: indexPath.row withObject:timedText];
```

Answer (score 0):

To use the cell:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [self tableView:self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This code

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
     //timedText = a NSString

    [timed replaceObjectAtIndex:indexpath.row withObject:timedText];
    [SpelerTable reloadData];
}
```

if everything right in your other code thn it will work.